# Get specific key value pairs with jq

Tags: json, bash, jq

In my sample json below,  I can filter records where charge is null with `jq -M ' map(select(.charge == null)) '`

```
  [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "vehicleA",
      "state": "available",
      "charge": 100
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "vehicleB",
      "state": "available",
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "vehicleB",
      "state": "available",
      "charge": 50
    }
  ]
```

which returns:

```
{
  "id": 2,
  "name": "vehicleB",
  "state": "available",
}
```

How would one only get `id` and the value associated with `id` of the filtered records so that adding this step to the above query would return `2`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is not exactly accurate:

- The example JSON is invalid, because the last property of the second object has a trailing comma, which should raise a parsing error
- The output of `map(select(.charge == null))` is not an object as in the example, but an array of a single object

In any case, you can extract the `.id` from the result of `map` like this:

```
jq -M 'map(select(.charge == null)) | .[].id' file.json
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you also include instructions on how to extract more than one specific key value pair? For example, if one wanted to include `name` as well?  Adding a comma  does this `| .[].name , .[].id`  but does not print the records side by side

Comment: @the_darkside you could write as `... | .[] | .id, .name`, but it also depends on the output format that you prefer

Answer (score 6):

If you would like an array of ids for items without a charge you could use this filter:

```
.items | map(select(.charge == null) | .id)
```

[Try it online at jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/K_-O_YrxD5)

If you want the values enumerated instead of being collected into an array this is better:

```
.items[] | select(.charge == null) | .id
```

[Try it online at jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/L-Rnd1C6yv)